# parallel.for question

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing

I have a foreach loop that processes a few thousand xmlnodes from an xmlnodelist.  I'm trying to integrate the Parallel.For options from .net 4 but I get an error that "No overload for method 'For' takes 3 arguments'.  But every example I see so far has it written this way.  Does someone know what I need to change to get this to compile?  Thanks.

Parallel.For( 0, jobs.Count, i =>
{
  //..do work here..
});

Comment: I think I figured it out.  My example code I showed here wasn't exactly what I had in my actual code.  I was doing Parallel.For<XmlNode>(0, jobs.Count....  Removing the type parameter worked.  Now the only other question I have is how do I break out of the current iteration?  It doesn't seem to like my continue statements.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the only other question I have is how do I break out of the current iteration? It doesn't seem to like my continue statements.

How exactly do you expect `continue` statements to work when each iteration can be running concurrently? You should read [How to: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx) on the MSDN for more information about this and take a look at the [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx) and [Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the only other question I have is how do I break out of the
>   current iteration? It doesn't seem to like my continue statements.

Instead of `continue`, use `break`.  Rather than:

```
for (int i = 1; i < jobs.Count; i++) {
    // Initialise iteration.
    if (iterationInvalid) continue;
    // Do work.
}
```

What you're essentially getting is:

```
for (int i = 1; i < jobs.Count; i++)
    action(i);

void action (int i) {
    // Initialise iteration.
    if (iterationInvalid) break;
    // Do work.
}
```

Comment: +1 it's worth noting that there is no actual `break` (in the normal sense) capability for Parallel.For